# How do I tell which locations on my drive are being written to?

Tags: macos

I often want to know where certain applications on my Mac store data.  Often, I just ask on SuperUser, for example, "Where does Stickies save note data?"  But, I'd like to know how to research the issue for myself.

**What tools can I use to track which files an application changes, and at what times?**

I know that I can use the System Profiler to see which files and ports an application has open, but I'd like a better solution.  I'd like to be able to see real-time, or afterwards but with timestamps, each time an application writes to a file, and which files it's writing to.

Comment: If this were a Windows question, I would've recommended RegShot in a heartbeat. I used to swear by that thing when I was doing PortableApps.com work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opensnoop in terminal seems pretty cool, see [this](http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/22/monitor-mac-os-x-filesystem-usage-access-with-opensnoop/) article describing it.

[image]